# Please wait for the User Profile Service (Please wait for the ProfSvc) - Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have a HPE ML30 Gen10 machine with RAID I configuration. In it is Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition. Inside Windows is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition, it has a 32 GB of RAM (ECC).

Windows suddenly began to randomly stuck at "Please wait for the User Profile Service", "Please wait for the ProfSvc" screen after installing SQL Server 2017 (Kindly see image below).

Once it got stuck in that screen I have no choice but to long press the power button to shut the machine down *(Note: I am shutting down our server everyday because of a recent fire incident that engulfed half of our office).*

Pressing the power button is also not working. It will also stuck into "Shutting down" screen after I press the power button once. (kindly see image below).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Jonathan